# Why is there no facility to overload static properties in PHP?

Tags: php, static-access, method-overloading, static-keyword

### Intro

PHP allows you to overload method calls and [property accesses](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) by declaring [magic methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) in classes. This enables code such as:

```
class Foo {
    public function __get($name) { return 42; }
}

$foo = new Foo;
echo $foo->missingProperty; // prints "42"
```

Apart from overloading instance properties and methods, since PHP 5.3.0 we can also overload `static` methods calls by overriding the magic method [`__callStatic`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic).

### Something missing

What is conspicuously missing from the available functionality is the ability to overload *static properties*, for example:

```
echo Foo::$missingProperty; // fatal error: access to undeclared static property
```

This limitation is clearly [documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get):

> Property overloading only works in object context. These magic methods
>   will not be triggered in static context. Therefore these methods
>   should not be declared `static`. As of PHP 5.3.0, a warning is issued if
>   one of the magic overloading methods is declared `static`.

### But why?

My questions are:

1. Is there a technical reason that this functionality is not currently supported? Or perhaps a (shudder) political reason?
2. Have there been any aborted attempts to add this functionality in the past?

Most importantly, the question **is not** "how can I have dynamic static properties in userland PHP?". That said, if you know of an especially cute implementation based on `__callStatic` that you want to share then by all means do so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=121578194822276&w=2

> Was static member overloading added in PHP 5.3? I noticed that static 
>   method overloading was (__callStatic). The two would complement each 
>   other and it just seems natural to add these as well. I did notice that 
>   they are apart of the "static-class" RFC and a bug report, but it would 
>   be nice to see these in 5.3. With this addition and LSB, php classes can 
>   do so much! Ex:
>
> ```
> __setStatic()
> __getStatic()
> __issetStatic()
> __unsetStatic()
> ```

Quoting follow-up http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=121578318524848&w=2

> if the RFC for static classes will be accepted, static property
>   interceptors will be a part of the next PHP major version (might it be
>   5.4 or 6). So it won't make it into 5.3, but we will have that hopefully
>   in the future.

Link to Static Classes RFC:

- https://wiki.php.net/rfc/static-classes

The Status of the RFC is "in the works" but given that it is from 2008 you might want to ask on the php.internals mailing list or on #php.pecl on EFNet IRC to find out what has become of it.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon, very helpful, as usual. ;-)  While the Static Classes RFC seems to propose support for `__getStatic()` and `__setStatic()` on *static* classes, it would still be useful to have this functionality for instantiable classes. Are you aware of any moves in this direction?

Comment: @DavidWeinraub nope, sorry. Tbh, I don't care about things related to static methods. I almost never find any good use for them and they lead to bad coupling and painful testing.

Comment: Absolutely agree! ;-) But some frameworks that are thrust upon me use statics for their model layer. `__getStatic()` would enable me to DRY up a lot of my existing code. Thanks!